# Accessing JSON-LD data by either short or fully qualified property name

Tags: javascript, json-ld

I've got some JSON-LD that has a context and vocabulary, and redefines a schema.org property, like so:

```
{
  "@context": [
    "http://schema.org/",
    {
      "@vocab": "http://ld.schema.example.com/sample#"
    }
  ],
  "http://ld.schema.example.com/sample#startDate": "2000-01-01T00:00:00",
  "Action": { "description": "sample"}
}
```

I need to read the `startDate` javascript. Easy enough:

```
const startDate = jsonData["http://ld.schema.example.com/sample#startDate"];
```

The trouble starts when I get this instead:

```
{
  "@context": {
    "@vocab": "http://ld.schema.example.com/sample#"
  },
  "@graph": [
    {
      "startDate": "2000-01-01T00:00:00"
    }
  ]
}
```

Now I need to access it with:

```
const startDate = jsonData.startDate
```

I'm trying to build reusable React components that display sections of the data I'm receiving. I'm trying to build a reusable vocabulary, but also leveraging well-known public vocabularies, such as schema.org, and I am not able to guarantee that we won't use an existing property name to mean something else entirely. And I can't guarantee that the data I'm receiving will always come in having been framed with schema.org included.

Short of re-framing the data when I receive it to add missing `@contexts` (or working with the expanded form), is there a solution to let me access that property without a clunky switch, ternary or if statement, regardless of the framing?